# Can't get lib file from port:8080 in Webpack, created by vue-cli

Tags: javascript, webpack, vue.js, webpack-2

I want to add some external file in Vue project like:

```
<script src="vlan/src/assets/js/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="vlan/src/assets/js/stats.min.js"></script>
```

[console error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nepxn.png)

The `http://localhost:8080/vlan/src/assets/js/stats.min.js` always show 404 error, but it works without adding the port。Did anyone met this before? I just want to know how to add lib file from the html template,please do't talk about `require` or `import` things, thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you simply want to add it in your index.html file as shown above or do you want to include in using webpack? Webpack does not want a full URL including port etc. you should only pass the relative path to the directory within your webpack build. If it works without port  - then your webserver is not setup correctly

Comment: the link you showed actually accesses the src folder. Usually you would copy the "external" scripts into your "public" area instead of accessing sources directly.